# Eclipse/Android: can't install Google APIs targets

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

To use a MapView in my android application, I need to to run it in a "Google APIs (Google Inc.)" [target](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html#avdsetup). However, I can't figure out how to download one.

In Eclipse, Android SDK and AVD Manager -> Third party add-ons -> Google Inc. -> No packages found

Although I can see that they are a bunch of packages available when looking at the [url](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml)

Same issue as [here](http://code.google.com/p/processing/issues/detail?id=879).

Here help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you don't already have them installed? If you have them installed you will still need to set the build target for your project to one of the Google apis instead of the standard android.

Comment: I don't think I have them installed, I don't see them in the installed packages list, and when I want to create a new avd, I only have the standard android targets in the list...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reference, here's how I solved this:

- I updated my [ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#updating)
- That gives me a new a new SDK manager in eclipse under Window. From there, I was able to install the missing API targets!