# Unfortunately,(ProjectName) has been stopped Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

I already generated API key by giving the MD5 fingureprint from here 
https://code.google.com/apis/console/?noredirect#project:413913157166:access

but after running the android application i got error message `Unfortunately,(ProjectName) has been stopped Android` in the emulator

Need Help.. Thanks in advance

here is my logcat

```
t. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
12-23 01:06:40.713: W/dalvikvm(1663): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 33 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
12-23 01:06:40.744: D/dalvikvm(1663): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
12-23 01:06:44.634: D/dalvikvm(1663): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 243K, 11% free 2773K/3104K, paused 41ms, total 47ms
12-23 01:06:44.634: W/CursorWrapperInner(1663): Cursor finalized without prior close()
12-23 01:06:44.645: W/CursorWrapperInner(1663): Cursor finalized without prior close()
12-23 01:06:44.724: D/AndroidRuntime(1663): Shutting down VM
12-23 01:06:44.744: W/dalvikvm(1663): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.maps/com.example.maps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.google.android.map.MapView
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.google.android.map.MapView
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at com.example.maps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     ... 11 more
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.map.MapView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.maps-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.maps-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
12-23 01:06:44.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1663):     ... 21 more
12-23 01:06:54.994: I/Process(1663): Sending signal. PID: 1663 SIG: 9
12-23 01:08:58.434: D/dalvikvm(1820): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 250K, 11% free 2766K/3104K, paused 67ms, total 76ms
12-23 01:08:58.434: W/CursorWrapperInner(1820): Cursor finalized without prior close()
12-23 01:08:58.464: W/CursorWrapperInner(1820): Cursor finalized without prior close()
12-23 01:08:58.624: D/AndroidRuntime(1820): Shutting down VM
12-23 01:08:58.624: W/dalvikvm(1820): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.maps/com.example.maps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.google.android.map.MapView
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.google.android.map.MapView
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at com.example.maps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     ... 11 more
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.map.MapView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.maps-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.maps-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
12-23 01:08:58.714: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     ... 21 more
12-23 01:09:10.654: I/Process(1820): Sending signal. PID: 1820 SIG: 9
12-23 01:16:40.084: D/dalvikvm(1913): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 229K, 11% free 2786K/3104K, paused 47ms, total 52ms
12-23 01:16:40.084: W/CursorWrapperInner(1913): Cursor finalized without prior close()
12-23 01:16:40.095: W/CursorWrapperInner(1913): Cursor finalized without prior close()
12-23 01:16:40.114: D/AndroidRuntime(1913): Shutting down VM
12-23 01:16:40.114: W/dalvikvm(1913): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.maps/com.example.maps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class activity
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class activity
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at com.example.maps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     ... 11 more
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.activity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.maps-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.maps-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
12-23 01:16:40.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     ... 21 more
12-23 01:16:46.515: I/Process(1913): Sending signal. PID: 1913 SIG: 9
12-23 01:25:04.063: D/dalvikvm(1967): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 232K, 11% free 2784K/3104K, paused 30ms, total 36ms
12-23 01:25:04.063: W/CursorWrapperInner(1967): Cursor finalized without prior close()
12-23 01:25:04.073: W/CursorWrapperInner(1967): Cursor finalized without prior close()
12-23 01:25:04.093: D/AndroidRuntime(1967): Shutting down VM
12-23 01:25:04.093: W/dalvikvm(1967): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.maps/com.example.maps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.map.MapView
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.map.MapView
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at com.example.maps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     ... 11 more
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.map.MapView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.maps-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.maps-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
12-23 01:25:04.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     ... 21 more
12-23 01:25:22.094: I/Process(1967): Sending signal. PID: 1967 SIG: 9
12-23 01:27:40.973: D/dalvikvm(2025): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 233K, 11% free 2783K/3104K, paused 32ms, total 38ms
12-23 01:27:40.973: W/CursorWrapperInner(2025): Cursor finalized without prior close()
12-23 01:27:40.973: W/CursorWrapperInner(2025): Cursor finalized without prior close()
12-23 01:27:41.003: D/AndroidRuntime(2025): Shutting down VM
12-23 01:27:41.003: W/dalvikvm(2025): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.maps/com.example.maps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.map.MapView
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.map.MapView
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at com.example.maps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     ... 11 more
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.map.MapView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.maps-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.maps-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
12-23 01:27:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     ... 21 more
12-23 01:32:41.724: I/Process(2025): Sending signal. PID: 2025 SIG: 9




HERE IS MY MANIFEST

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.maps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name ="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.maps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
</i>
```

HERE IS MY ACTIVITY CLASS

```
package com.example.maps;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

    MapView map;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mvMainActivity);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

HERE IS MY XML->LAYOUT FILE

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.google.android.map.MapView
        android:id = "@+id/mvMainActivity"
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true" 
        android:apiKey = "AIzaSyBq4zldj_kQVdwGt9ru-nWSSOJ0ORUBuFE"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: looks like you are using map api v1 which is deprecated. use map api v2

Comment: try removing the textview from the relative layout, sometimes such error occur if elements position are not specified properly

Comment: @Ankit The exception pretty clearly says it's the `MapView` causing the problem.

Comment: removed the textView part from the relativeLayout but still same problem occurs.

Comment: so how can i solve the MapView error part can you tell me please.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you update the ADK's libraries. [This question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9950609/170781) details how to update your libraries.

Furthermore, verify that the libraries you imported for `com.google.android.maps` have been added to your build path. It seems an off thing to check but working with Android, I have seen many stranger things!

Edit: As stated by one of the comments, the deprecated maps library might be the culprit. If the update does not fix the problem. Try raising the minimum version you are targeting. Legacy support is nice but often induces more problems than it solves. Unless it is of crucial importance to you, I would personally only target the latest release which I believe was API version 14 or 16.

Comment: thanks sir but how could i verify "verify that the libraries you imported for com.google.android.maps have been added to your build path"??

Comment: It would depend on your IDE. I'll go with the popular choice and explain for Eclipse. First off, if the ID does not complain when you write your import statement (or it could generate it automatically) the library should be referenced just fine. Maybe an outdated version, but the library contains the class you wanted by name. You can also see it in your file tree of the project. There are a couple of library collections like `Android [version number]`, `Android Private Libraries`, or `Android Dependencies`. The reference should be located in one of these!

Answer (score 0):

yup as Raghunandan said you are using Google maps API V1 which is deprecated one. Follow [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2) link for Convert it to API V2.

And also you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372399/running-google-map-application-on-android-emulator/19407415#19407415) code which I got map on my emulator.