# Download Google's API in Android SDK Manager

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

According to Android documentation, Google API is included in Android 4.0.3(API15), however, it did not download for me and there is no option for me to add third party APIs anywhere (see image below)

[image]

Is there a way to add Google APIs by Google Inc.?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it appear in any other API versions?

Answer (score 3):

I Googled your question, and it turned out another StackOverflow question regarding this matter.
Maybe this solution would help you.

[Eclipse/Android: can't install Google APIs targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892220/eclipse-android-cant-install-google-apis-targets)

Basically it says you need to update your ADT Plugin for the eclipse.

try performing the update that shows up in your ADT (can see it in the image you posted)

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

When I run my SDK manager the Google APIs shows up under Android 4.0.3. Maybe update your Android SDK Tools?